# Punycode converter at C#

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, punycode

I need a punycode converter for Silverlight. For WPF have such an opportunity in the standard libraries. I need a ready-made library or code of functions (punycode encoding and decoding) {C#, Silverlight}.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Silverlight has access to this namespace but take a look at these [IdnMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.idnmapping.getascii%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) fuunctions which are built into the .net framework.