# Convert from and to puny code to unicode using c#?

Tags: c#, punycode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Punycode converter at C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125566/punycode-converter-at-c-sharp)

I am looking to convert a [puny code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) to unicode using C#.

I did come across few js including this one called ["punycode.js"](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-free-javascript-for-punycode-to-unicode-conversion) on SO.

But my requirement is to do the same using C#, the reason being

> I am making WEB API and need to use C# to do this conversion operation and then return the data through the API.. so no JS

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: TLDR, you want somebody to port some javascript code to C# for you?

Comment: @JonSkeet but the question does not have any solution which I can use for my this problem. Thanks for pointing me out to this link btw.

Comment: Well given that there are two solutions there, you should edit your question to explain *why* you can't use them.